# How to disable button if there is a def working?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've tried the code below to block a button, because if it is clicked while the def start is working it blows whole app. The button calls both defs start and block, although function start is not working at all.

The problem is that I can't put `button_start.config(state=tk.DISABLED)` in `def start():`, because it changes every 1000 ms and the button is weirdly pulsating.

I've searched it and that is my idea to deal with it. I'm not a pro coder and this might be stupid so I am counting on your expirience.

```
root = tk.Tk()
def stop_app():
    button_start.config(state=tk.NORMAL)


def start(): 
    #something working here...
    root.after(1000, start)
def block():
    button_start.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

button_start = tk.Button( root, command=start and block)
button_start.place(x=250, y=235)

button_stop = tk.Button(root, command=stop_app)
button_stop.place(x=305, y=235)
```

Comment: first logical line in `start` should be `button_start.config(state=tk.DISABLED)` and it is solved, isnt it ?

Comment: `command=start and block` doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can remove the separate `block()` function altogether, put `button_start.config(state=tk.DISABLED)` at the beginning of `start()`, and change `command=start and block` to `command=start`.

Comment: @martineau I was trying to call both of the functions

Comment: You can do something like that with `command=lambda: start() and block()`.

Comment: I have edited my question so you. The problem is thaht function start is recalled every 1000 ms and because of that the button is pulsating like it is clikcked every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be making things too complicated. The code below simply toggles the states of the two `Button`s depending on the state of the first one so they are always the opposite of one another.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('350x350')

def start_app():
    if button_start.cget('state') == tk.NORMAL:
        button_start.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        button_stop.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

def stop_app():
    if button_stop.cget('state') == tk.NORMAL:
        button_stop.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        button_start.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

button_start = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start_app, state=tk.NORMAL)
button_start.place(x=250, y=235)

button_stop = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop_app, state=tk.DISABLED)
button_stop.place(x=305, y=235)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshots showing before clicking on the <kbd>Start</kbd> button and after doing so:

[image: screenshots of before and after]

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate your work.

Answer (score 0):

The line,

```py
button_start = tk.Button(root, command=start and block)
```

has an error, `command=start and block`. You can’t have 2 functions for the same button.

What you can do instead of this is:

```py
def block():
    button_start.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

def start():
    block()
```

Or the same thing but with lesser number of lines:

```py
def start():
    button_start.config(tk.DISABLED)
```

And change the line with the error to:

```py
button_start = tk.Button(root, command=start)
```

Comment: The problem is thaht function start is recalled every 1000 ms and because of that the button is pulsating like it is clikcked every second.

Comment: @Kyle2115 Maybe you can make some kind of `variable` in your program, set it to `true/false`, and then disable the button only when it is not already.